# Is it the sampling process, not the population distribution, that makes the CLT central limit theorem work?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, sampling

I find it a bit "mathemagical" that one can use a sample to estimate the parameters of the assumed normal distribution of the true population, even if the sample is not at all close to normally distributed!

So, we use the sample data only to fill in the few parameters of a Student's t-function: The sample mean, the standard deviation and the number of observations (adjusted for the degrees of freedom used up). Then we ignore the actual sample data from there on. It all being reduced to 3 figures. Even if the sample's frequency histogram shows a ragged pack of bars here and there. We instead use the beautifully symmetric curve of the t-distribution to actually test our hypothesis.

I heard today, from a professional (not academic) source that this is because THE SAMPLING PROCESS is assumed to be normally distributed. So it doesn't relate to how the actual data in the population is distributed.

I do see how the sampling process can be reliably randomized and that it will then follow the normal distribution with respect to what observations are picked up by the sample. But I wish to see that line of reasoning developed.

How come the true distribution of the population doesn't matter, but only the sampling process? And why then is sometimes for example the exponential distribution used instead? Not because of using a different sampling process, I suppose.

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. Can you state precisely the statement you find « mathemagical »?

Comment: That the t-distribution is used to represent a sample that is not at all distributed in a similar way. The sample data could be uniformly distributed, but still the t-distribution is used to test the significance of hypotheses about the population.

Comment: Hum, still not clear to me. I encourage you to write at least a formula. I don't even understand if you are looking for a proof of something, or insight, or a hand-waving argument... What does it even mean, that the "sampling process is normally distributed"?

Comment: It seems I was confused by someone misleading me. The population must be normally distributed for the t-test based on the sample to work. So if the sample is not at all normally distributed, then perhaps the population isn't and it is a bad idea to use the t-test, right?